# After upgrading to iOS 5, how to restore my apps?

Tags: ios, upgrade

I've just upgraded to iTunes 5 and iOS 5 and after the process completed, my apps are missing from my device. I can still see them in iTunes under Library/Apps folder, how do I push them to the device? (I've tried sync already but it did nothing.)

Comment: Are they checked for sync in the Applications pane on iTunes?

Comment: What Nichoas said.  In iTunes, check the items you wish to sync, then sync them to the iOS device.  For some reason, some items may become unchecked during the upgrade.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you connect your iPad/iPhone you choose your device in left column under the Devices section, then got the Apps tab and select the Apps you want to sync.

Afterwards, select "Synchronize" at the bottom right to update your iDevice.